# Where can I find a complete/non-biased comparison of available C++ logging libraries?

Tags: library, c++, logs

I'm currently using a log4j-derived logging library for C++, and I've seen some new libraries that seems to be written in a more modern C++ (C++11 or beyond).

I wonder if there is some good and non-biased comparison of logging libraries for C++. I'm not necessarily interested in the best performance/c++conformance/, I'd like to see a broad comparison of different aspects of those libraries, their strengths and weaknesses, community support and interest trends and any other information that can be useful to choose one library or another.

Sorry if this question seems trivial, but after some search on the web I just found old info, very narrow comparisons, a few personal opinions on a specific library or just library authors opinions.

So my question is: where can I find some good and non-biased comparison of logging libraries for C++. Websites, whitepapers or whatever.

Comment: This site is for recommending software rather than pointers to reviews of software, especially since the quality and degree of bias are often a matter of opinion. It might be a good idea to reword your question to be a request for modern, C++ logging libraries with their respective advantages - this will hopefully generate some unbiased reviews.

Comment: Only gratis, or also commerical?

Comment: @Mawg Do you mean free/commercial logging libraries, or free/commercial comparisons? In both cases I would prefer freely available libraries and comparison info, but I'm open to commercial stuff, if not biased

Answer (score 1):

good luck with that :-)

More seriously, though, you can:

- Compare followers, forks and star'ers on GitHub, for those libraries which are hosted on GitHub. That's an imperfect, but unbiased, measure of interest and popularity.
- There's a seemingly fair, though biased-by-definition, comparison of performance on [spdlog's GitHub page](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog). It's backed by the code used for benchmarking, so you could try it out yourself or modify it if you feel it's biased.

I'm actually going to be needing a logging library myself in the near future, so if you other comparisons don't hesitate to post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this can be useful to others,
one of the websites I've found that contains a list of the most "popular" logging c++ libraries and some one-to-one comparison is the "logging" category on [Awesome C++](https://cpp.libhunt.com/categories/779-logging).
This seems to be mostly focused on project development activity and popularity (i.e. on github).
It does not contain a "complete" comparison or table of technical information (i.e. compliancy to which C++standard level, is it header-only or not, ...), but it may be a good starting point to skim a long list of options.